# Is there a way to differentiate between automated email id vs real email id

Tags: algorithm, parsing, email

You should know that I am not speaking about spams. Also I understand this is not an easy problem to solve.

**My Goal:** I am writing simple algorithm to rank the users who are emailing me. Probably I can come up with a score based on how frequently they email me, whether I reply to their emails or not. so on..

But I have a problem with automated systems like Facebook notifications, unsubscribe, mailman, google alerts, who email me often. And I don't want to consider them as a friend and don't want to give them rank.

**Question:** Is there any way I can tell if the email is from automated emailid based on some standard header parameter, or look for popular keywords(this isn't full proof, I understand)

EDIT:
Consider that I have no access to sent emails..

suggestions please...

Comment: if you have a good heuristic then they should get a low rank. For example, they will have high receive/reply ratio.

Comment: edited.. Good point, but I forgot to put a condition if I don't want to look into sent emails..

Comment: Didn't you say you wanted to base the rank in part on how often you replied to the e-mails?

Comment: Yes I did. Otherwise the question is too simple.